# Calling custom function in asp.net MVC web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an authenticate function in my company controller

```
    [ActionName("Authenticate")]
    [HttpGet]
    public bool Authenticate(Company company)
    {
        if (Uow.Companies.AuthenticateCompany(company))            
            return true;                
        return false;
    }
```

that is called using the following ajax query

```
$.ajax({ url: "/api/company/Authenticate", type: 'get', data: company })
```

company is a js object

```
Company: function (name, phoneNumber, password) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.password = password;
}

var company = new Company($('#TextBoxCompanyName').val(),'00000000', $('#TextBoxCompanyPassword').val());
```

and my api route is as follows

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Action",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
    );
```

When the code runs the web api calls the following function in the company controller

```
 public Company Get(int id)
    {
        return Uow.Companies.GetById(id);
    }
```

How do I call a custom get function?

Comment: What is `company` in the JS (`$.ajax`) code?

Comment: @carlosfigueira made an update

Comment: The order of the routes matters. If you have multiple routes then the `"Action"` should comes first then the default one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web.API tries to match the routes in the definition order.

From [Web API Routing and Actions/Routing and Action Selection](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection)

> The framework tries to match the segments in the URI path to the template. Literals in the template must match exactly. A placeholder matches any value, unless you specify constraints. The framework does not match other parts of the URI, such as the host name or the query parameters. **The framework selects the first route in the route table that matches the URI.**

So the order of definition of the routes matter.

You need to put your `"Action"` **before** the `"DefaultApi"`

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Action",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
    );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Otherwise the wep.api interprets your url `/api/company/Authenticate` as controller=company and id=Authenticate so it routes to your Get action.

Comment: Thanks, The company data is not being sent through. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: In the case of `GET` request and complex types like `Company` you need to annotate your parameter with `FromUriAttribute` : `public bool Authenticate([FromUri]Company company) {` more info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx